# Type based on a subset of another type whose keys start with a specific string

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type from another type. That type would contain a subset of keys based on their prefix.

Example base type:

```
interface Foo {
  axisControl: FormControl;
  directionControl: FormControl;

  filteredAxis: Observable<string[]>;
  filteredDirection: Observable<string[]>;
}

type Bar = // I want to write something only based on the prefix "filtered"
```

Expected result:

```
{
  filteredAxis: Observable<string[]>;
  filteredDirection: Observable<string[]>;
}
```

Is that possible and how?

What I have tried so far:

```
Pick<Foo, `filtered${string}`>
```

But that throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow down the picked type with intersection:

```
type FooWithFiltered = Pick<Foo, `filtered${string}` & keyof Foo>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwAewAzgMLrhToA2AXMqWFKAOYDc+yAJsFBARhgVStTqNmrEJ1zcYwWpAE8AgiVKSW7LgQVLoEHgBF+g4VS3TZAXzm4wATwAOKDOgDqwMAAtUi5SNkAF5kAAVgBABrAB53ABpkAAN9QJ4AEmwpdhsk5AAyZCiIR3QYNEwAPm4gA)

Comment: Thanks your answer is the actual answer to my question. Here is my actual [full use case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1pgB4EsIGF4A7AFwCd4QAuaCcnIgc2gF5oAiOshx9gbnTQAJjjIBTYCRzFCpCtVr0mrDlx79UggGY4QJMeKEBBXBBpqmAbQC6Ky5yW9rAjDr0GxQgCKiJU4uaONnYO3EzszpoY+nQAFG76hgByYAC2YjQABgkeQgAkyBaMAL6Z0ABk0ADWYgCe8FrQJAAWeACUaBgYwMR00ABuYNxgAEYgYioteJY5yWlikRjFqMVAA) do you know why `variable` is not of type `string[]` when I hover it? I know this might be another question but I ask here just in case you have an immediate answer.

Comment: You might have to create another type that explicitly narrow it down first. it works with [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1pgB4EsIGF4A7AFwCd4QAuaCcnIgc2gF5oAiOshx9gbnTQAJjjIBTYCRzFCpCtVr0mrDlx79UggGY4QJMeKEBBXBBpqmAbQC6Ky5yW9rAjDr0GxQgCKiJU4uaONnYO3EzszpoY+nQAFG76hgByYAC2YjQI8LC6iZ4AlGgYGMDEdNAAbmDcYABGIGIqJAAWeJYJHkIp6ZEYAL6oA6gkAJ4ADo1ZOe6GKgAGHYYAJMgWjH1z0ABk0ADWYiPwWnCIQA)